# Predicting with function `arima` producing NaN values in R

Tags: r

I am using arima function for intraday forecasting. Data is available for every 15 minute in a day. In the code below, it is working fine except for a few values of i in the for loop. output is displayed for i=223. predict function produces NaN values. I have checked the dataset, there is no NaN value there. Kindly suggest me how to get rid of this problem.

```
predict1=c()

predict2=c()

for(i in 1:456){

  y1n=ts(nbl$nbp[(12385+(i-1)*4):(15356+(i-1)*4)],frequency=96)

  y1n[which(is.na(y1n))]=y1n[which(is.na(y1n))-96]

  arima1=arima(y1n,order=c(1,1,0),seasonal=c(2,1,1),method="CSS")

  predict1=predict(arima1,8)

  predict2[(((i-1)*4)+1):(((i-1)*4)+4)]=predict1$pred[5:8]

}

arima1

Call:

arima(x = y1n, order = c(1, 1, 0), seasonal = c(2, 1, 1), method = "CSS")

Coefficients:

         ar1     sar1     sar2     sma1

         0.0241  -0.1122  -0.1068  -0.7830

    s.e.    0.0188   0.0240   0.0224   0.0189


sigma^2 estimated as 1490:  part log likelihood = -14583.05

> predict1=predict(arima1,8)

> predict1

$pred

Time Series:

Start = c(31, 93) 

End = c(32, 4) 

Frequency = 96 

[1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN


$se

Time Series:

Start = c(31, 93) 

End = c(32, 4) 

Frequency = 96 

[1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Maybe it's possible to have the data y1n for i=223 ?

Comment: I have encountered the similar questions when I predict with the model function pls/spls/plsda from R package mixOmics